# Problems with if and else if, c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to make a program that converts japanese characters into english characters but I have a weird problem and I cant figure out what how to solve it, I did find out what caused it though.

I'm using a dataset and I'm using this code to convert the characters

My problem is that it doesn't want to convert certain characters, and the characters it doesn't want to convert are based on what I set here:

```
// Sets fromtype to the type the character(s) currently is/are
string fromtype = "";
if (CharacterTable.Select("Romaji like '%" + character + "%'") != null)
{
    fromtype = "Romaji";
}
else if (CharacterTable.Select("Hiragana like '%" + character + "%'") != null)
{
    fromtype = "Hiragana";
}
else if (CharacterTable.Select("Katakana like '%" + character + "%'") != null)
{
    fromtype = "Katakana";
}
```

If I change every individual  line to "if", then it doesn't want to recognise romaji characters, if i set it to "else if" like right now, it sees.

Here is the full code:

```
DataSet CharacterDatabase = new DataSet();
DataTable CharacterTable = CharacterDatabase.Tables.Add();

//-- Add columns to the data table
CharacterTable.Columns.Add("Romaji", typeof(string));
CharacterTable.Columns.Add("Hiragana", typeof(string));
CharacterTable.Columns.Add("Katakana", typeof(string));

//-- Add rows to the data table
CharacterTable.Rows.Add("a", "?", "?");

// Sets fromtype to the type the character(s) currently is/are
string fromtype = "";
if (CharacterTable.Select("Romaji like '%" + character + "%'") != null)
{
    fromtype = "Romaji";
}
else if (CharacterTable.Select("Hiragana like '%" + character + "%'") != null)
{
    fromtype = "Hiragana";
}
else if (CharacterTable.Select("Katakana like '%" + character + "%'") != null)
{
    fromtype = "Katakana";
}

// generates a new variable to store the return in
DataRow[] filteredRows = CharacterTable.Select(fromtype + " like '%" + character + "%'");

// Return the converted character in the requested type
foreach (DataRow row in filteredRows)
{
    if (RequestedCharType == 1)
    {
        return row["Romaji"].ToString();
    }
    if (RequestedCharType == 2)
    {
        return row["Hiragana"].ToString();
    }
    if (RequestedCharType == 3)
    {
        return row["Katakana"].ToString();
    }
}

// if it couldn't find the character, return the original character
return character;
```

Comment: It seems like you solved your own question.  What is the remaining issue, if any?

Comment: The remaining problem is that wether or not I use if or else if, theres always something that doesn't convert, and i'm too stupid to understand why

Comment: If you use all Ifs, then you're probably overwriting the value you find in your first If by falling into another If, in which you also set the value for "fromtype".  I'm not too familiar with this CharacterTable you're using, but I also suspect you might get more accurate results by just having three arrays or lists of romaji, hiragana, and katakana, and looping through each to find out which array the passed character is in with a definitive == and not 'like'.  Should be no performance issue, because of how small those arrays or lists would be.

Comment: Nope I don't think so because every character only appears once in the entire database, so it's not like it appears in multiple rows. And alright thanks, I'll take that into consideration if I don't find an answer. I'm still pretty new to this so I just used the first option I found.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt Also, I don't know much about this but I think it will cause preformance issues, if people wrote a long text, it'd have to loop each character through a list of what will in time be several thousand characters

Comment: Ah you're probably right :) I was imagining some kind of application where you are only passing one character.  Good luck, wish I could help more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider what happens if a character matches multiple types.  It is possible that regardless of the `if` or `if else`, you choose a `fromtype` that doesn't have a matching result in the database.

You could consider some sort of scoring mechanism, where you query each type, and if the character matches multiple types, you take into consideration which types have replacements available.

Comment: It shouldn't be able to, it's character per character so, and in another function i've already written something that filters it when a japanese character contains multiple english letters for example (it will send for example "ta" as a charcter to this function and convert it that way)

Answer (score 0):

You assume that DataTable.Select() returns a null when there is no match.  It doesn't, it returns an empty array.  Your test should look like this:

```
 if (CharacterTable.Select("blabla").Length > 0) { // etc.. }
```